# Jython registering class with kryonet

Tags: java, jython, kryo, kryonet

I want to register a python/jython class with kryonet. I get this Error when I try it:

TypeError: register(): 1st arg can't be coerced to com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Registration, java.lang.Class

using `kr.register(MyPythonClass)`

is it somehow possible to let kryonet serialize python classes?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
kr.register(MyPythonClass.__class__)
```